# What should be done about the books tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tagwiki

I just reviewed some unanswered questions to get on the list for
the next clean up. I stumbled upon the [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag, the tag wiki
says:

> [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) is for questions which deal with books about TeX, LaTeX
>   and other topics of this site. For questions regarding design and
>   layout of books use [book-design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-design) instead.

There are currently 116 questions marked. I started with the
newest answers first, and most of them should be tagged [book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book)
instead. I collected the links to questions are are correctly
tagged (unexpectedly many I have to say). Some of them should
maybe tagged [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation), but this is ok for me.

The second part needs attention because neither [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) nor
[book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) apply.

```
116 - 41 - 13 = 62
```

62 questions that could be retagged to [book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book).
Unfortunately, i didn't collect the links to them. Would have
saved some time.

What do we do? Retag them in the next two weeks? tohecz
retagged the [space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) questions a while ago. 
Are there any alternatives coming to mind?

The topic was raised in a little different manner a while back: [The {books} and {book-design} tags](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/883/the-books-and-book-design-tags)

#### Tag applies

<sub>- [Books for Library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182872/books-for-library)

- [What is the best book with american typography rules?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173207/what-is-the-best-book-with-american-typography-rules)

- [Are there good books retracing the history of (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148968/are-there-good-books-retracing-the-history-of-latex)

- [Looking for an ebook about typography that used to be part of a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124265/looking-for-an-ebook-about-typography-that-used-to-be-part-of-a-package)

- [What non-free books are available and recommended?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113158/what-non-free-books-are-available-and-recommended)

- [Why should I buy a TeX/LaTeX guide book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111703/why-should-i-buy-a-tex-latex-guide-book)

- [Electronic version of Knuth's "TeXbook"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110836/electronic-version-of-knuths-)

- [LaTeX Companions Third Revised Boxed Set, The](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107413/latex-companions-third-revised-boxed-set-the)

- [An old italian translation of The TeXbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101128/an-old-italian-translation-of-the-)

- [The TeXbook: Spiral or hard-cover binding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100060/)

- [Is there any textbook for XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99793/is-there-any-textbook-for-xelatex)

- [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384/latex-introductions-in-languages-other-than-english)

- [a book recommendation for doing graphics in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79294/a-book-recommendation-for-doing-graphics-in-beamer)

- [How does TeX actually work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77918/how-does-tex-actually-work)

- [Where‎ ‎do‎ I start ‎learning‎ conditional tests ‎in ‎LaTeX‎?‎](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73239/where-do-i-start-learning-conditional-tests-in-latex)

- [LaTeX Companion as an ebook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66863/latex-companion-as-an-ebook)

- [New Edition of TeXBook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63884/new-edition-of-)

- [\@ifnextchar and friends documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59402/ifnextchar-and-friends-documentation)

- [A critique of TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58501/a-critique-of-tex)

- [What book do you recommend for new Tex users?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57911/what-book-do-you-recommend-for-new-tex-users)

- [LaTeX presentations like OpenOffice .odp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56978/latex-presentations-like-openoffice-odp)

- [Learning TeX via the TeXbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51695/learning-tex-via-the-)

- [What is the latest edition of Knuth's "Computers & Typesetting" Series?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40543/what-is-the-latest-edition-of-knuths-computers-typesetting-series)

- [Resources for learning about contributed packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36968/resources-for-learning-about-contributed-packages)

- [Beyond Bringhurst: mathematical typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32012/beyond-bringhurst-mathematical-typesetting)

- [If I'm about to write a book on LaTeX, should I wait for a LaTeX3 release?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31758/if-im-about-to-write-a-book-on-latex-should-i-wait-for-a-latex3-release)

- [Topics for a book about LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27941/topics-for-a-book-about-luatex)

- [Which books can I read via texdoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27636/which-books-can-i-read-via-texdoc)

- [How on earth did Knuth do it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24671/how-on-earth-did-knuth-do-it)

- [What are good advanced LaTeX books?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24105/what-are-good-advanced-latex-books)

- [Are there any good general typesetting books / references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13874/are-there-any-good-general-typesetting-books-references)

- [Good LaTeX book for Math beginner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13113/good-latex-book-for-math-beginner)

- [Should I read Donald Knuth's The TeXbook?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/should-i-read-donald-knuths-the-)

- [Brown paper strip on page 125 of The METAFONTbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10187/brown-paper-strip-on-page-125-of-the-metafontbook)

- [Good XeTeX Books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5711/good-xetex-books)

- [Help in choosing LaTeX2e books in light of LaTeX3 development](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5688/help-in-choosing-latex2e-books-in-light-of-latex3-development)

- [Reference about "modern" LaTeX usage for scientific works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5534/reference-about-modern-latex-usage-for-scientific-works)

- [Where can I find good ConTeXt documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/where-can-i-find-good-context-documentation)

- [Is there a comprehensive and complete LaTeX reference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/is-there-a-comprehensive-and-complete-latex-reference)

- [Which manuals are on your "TeX Reference" shelf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66/which-manuals-are-on-your-tex-reference-shelf)

- [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)</sub>

#### Complete retag needed

<sub>- ["LaTeX does not work well for people who have sold their souls"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170824/latex-does-not-work-well-for-people-who-have-sold-their-souls)

- [Links of book templates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122496/links-of-book-templates)

- [Robert Sedgewick - Algorithms Fourth Edition Style in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111710/robert-sedgewick-algorithms-fourth-edition-style-in-latex)

- [Typeset Like Jackson's E&M](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87072/typeset-like-jacksons-em)

- [Latex style that resembles the one used in some computer science books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62435/latex-style-that-resembles-the-one-used-in-some-computer-science-books)

- [Unix Text Processing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57361/unix-text-processing)

- [TeX family tree with timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42594/tex-family-tree-with-timeline)

- [References for learning how to check for typesetting problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37379/references-for-learning-how-to-check-for-typesetting-problems)

- [Authoring RPG books in LaTeX: what packages to use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24218/authoring-rpg-books-in-latex-what-packages-to-use)

- [How to write a book in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/how-to-write-a-book-in-latex)

- [Varying images at varying positions in Book and Memoir class chapter styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14221/varying-images-at-varying-positions-in-book-and-memoir-class-chapter-styles)

- [The cross-reference boxes in TeX: the program](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10215/the-cross-reference-boxes-in-tex-the-program)

- [Comprehensive book on Kile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9680/comprehensive-book-on-kile)</sub>

Comment: Why does the Kile one need to be retagged? It is true that it asks about Kile, which is just an editor, but it the question is clearly a bit more general. I don't see why this needs a 'complete retag'...

Comment: @cfr I would have suggested *documentation* or *manuals* but the tag-wiki shows me that this would be wrong. It was just a quick skim of the questions.

Comment: @Johannes_B As for the tag wiki of {[tag:documentation]}, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/the-documentation-tag ...

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for editing. Do you have any ideas on the question?

Comment: Why `book` is not the tag for the standard `book` class (like `report` or `article`)?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Excellent question, i just noticed, that {bbok} is a synonym for books (books related to TeX and friends)

Comment: Related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/why-are-there-books-and-amsbook-tags-but-no-book-class-tag

Answer (score 6):

I think we have here a tag that is so broad as to be meaningless. As suggested in a [comment](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5696/what-should-be-done-about-the-books-tag#comment16502_5696), [book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) should presumably apply to things specific to the `book` class in analogy to [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article) or [report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/report). On the other hand, I'm not really sure what [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) means: it might be books about TeX, creating books, *etc.* I'd therefore suggest that one goes in favour of either [book-design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-design) or [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation), as appropriate. Once that is done we can deal with [books](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) by making it a synonym of one of the two 'better' tags.

Comment: Seems like a good idea.

Comment: [tag:book-design] sounds good. As for [tag:documentation], somewhere deep in my head lies a trace of a memory that we wanted to distinguish [tag:books-about-latex] from general [tag:documentation], but I may be wrong.

Comment: @tohecz [The {documentation} tag](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2544) and [Tags about documentation](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1751)

Comment: there are a couple of related questions that make good sense, but have never been acted on: [Tags for document classes](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/402/579) and [Why are there {books} and {amsbook} tags but no {book} (class) tag?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3728/579).  the suggested tag "book-class" (or even "book-classes" to allow for similar  but differently named classes) hasn't been created but i think is still needed.  if this is acceptable, i'm willing to create it and retag.  yes?  no?